# push - добавление элемента в JS.А наоборот?

Tags: javascript

Как сделать чтобы элемент (объект) никогда не смог добавиться?например, в массив?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно [заморозить](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) массив:

```js
const array = [1,2,3];
Object.freeze(array);
console.log(array);

array.push(4); // Cannot add property
```

Можно повесить на него [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), который не пустит какой-то конкретный элемент:

```js
const four = 'You shall not pass!'

const array = new Proxy(['one', 'two', 'three'], {
  set: (target, property, value) => {
    if(value === four) return false;
    target[property] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

array.push('something');
console.log(array);
array.push(four); // trap returned falsish
```